# Transformer primary input

Tags: transformer

I have a 100 kW pole mount transformer primary input is 34.5 kV. Secondary is 277 V. I have to change provider and the new primary will be 12.47 kV. Can I use the transformer with 12.47 kV primary and still get secondary of 277 V?

Comment: If you need to ask strangers on the internet on anything grid connected in the tens of kV level, you are simply not qualified. Please call a high voltage electrician before anyone gets electrocuted.

Comment: You will need to check with the provider.

Comment: Here's a short video showing why you let the provider deal with these things: [Electrical Arc Flash Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY).

Answer (score 2):

The secondary voltage of a transformer is related to the primary voltage by the turns ratio.

For the existing transformer you have 34500 V / 277 V for a ratio of 124.55. If you divide the new primary voltage by the turns ratio you get 12470 V / 124.55 = 100.12 V on the secondary.

Also, for the same power, the lower primary voltage will need more current. For 100 kW with the higher voltage it will be around 3 A, while the lower voltage would need around 8 A for 100 kW. The primary needs to be rated to handle this current.

Unless the transformer was designed to be able to use both voltages by having multiple windings that could be connected in different combinations you won't be able to use it as is.

You could look into having it rewound, there are companies that do this sort of thing, you would have to look into that to see if it's economically worth it over the cost of a new transformer.

As said in the comments, this is something you'll have to work out with the provider and qualified electricians.

Comment: Could the OP rewind the transformer? (C|N>K)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Can OP re-qualify it after said rewind for PD, insulation, temp rise, voltage withstand + whatever the grid owner demands at a certified agency?

Comment: @AndrewMorton This is a 100 kW transformer, you don't mess with those yourself. Besides the obvious electrical shock danger it's most likely oil filled, possibly containing toxic PCBs if it's an old one, and they weigh something like half a ton. Maybe if there's someone that does this professionally and can re-certify it like winny says it could be done.